# zclip (zeroclipboard) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I am trying to use zclip, but it just doesn't want to work. I have included the zclip js file, jquery and the zeroclipboard swf.

So this is my js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#copy1').zclip({
        path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('a#copyx1').text()
    });
});
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.sample.co.uk" target="_blank" id="copyx1">http://www.sample.co.uk/</a>
    <a id="copy1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy1">Copy to clipboard</button></a>
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [zClip don't work - multiple copy to clipboard JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486979/zclip-dont-work-multiple-copy-to-clipboard-js/30573503#30573503)

I could not get this to work on my server, I downloaded the ZeroClipboard.swf from zclips website and would not work. I noticed that the swf on zclips website in not the one that they use for their examples. So I created a hyperlink to http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf and clicked "save link as" compared the size to the one I had downloaded originally and it was bigger. So I put the new one from the link above onto my server and it worked perfectly.

I think if you downloaded the swf from zclips website directly from their download link, this is your problem as it was mine. Try saving my link as a file and then uploading it to your server.

Try that and get back to me